# R how to get a list of characters in a string

Tags: r, string, character

In R how could i get list of characters that are contained in a string. I have provided an example below

```
somefunction("abc")
should return
"a","b","c"
```

=============================update1

I am planning to get all the characters, sort them and join them back. I tried paste function but it didnt work :( Any inputs?

```
sort(strsplit('cba','')[[1]])
paste(sort(strsplit('cba','')[[1]]))
```

Comment: `strsplit('abc','')[[1]]`

Comment: You have to use `collapse=''`) i.e. `paste(sort(strsplit('cba','')[[1]]), collapse='')`

Comment: please put your comments as answer so that i can accept it

Comment: I posted it as solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
strsplit('abc','')[[1]]
```

Comment: would it be possible to provide an answer to my update1?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 paste(sort(strsplit('cba','')[[1]]), collapse='')
 #[1] "abc"
```